# ScalaTest: How to mix parallel and sequential tests

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scalatest

Say I have 6 test suites: A B C D E F, and I want A B C to run sequentially and **THEN** run D E F in parrallel. 
With an output like that:

```
A
B
C // always in that order
E
D
F // The order doesn't matter
```

The idea is to be able to test ABC in isolation of the rest of the tests.

**What I have already tried**

Create a super sequential test class like that and adding `@DoNotDiscover` on the sequential tests.

```scala
class MasterSuite extends Stepwise(
  Sequential(new A, new B, new C)
)
```

But, even if A B C are run sequentially, then are run in parrallel with the other tests.

I have also tried that

```scala
class MasterSuite extends Stepwise(
  Sequential(new A, new B, new C),
  Suites(new D, new E, new F)
)
```

But for me it run me all tests sequentially (maybe I have miss something in the `build.sbt` file).

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `Stepwise` says the following:

> The difference between Stepwise and Sequential is that although Stepwise executes its own nested suites sequentially, **it passes whatever distributor was passed to it to those nested suites**. Thus the nested suites could run their own nested suites and tests in parallel if that distributor is defined. By contrast, Sequential always passes None for the distributor to the nested suites, so any and every test and nested suite contained within the nested suites passed to the Sequential construtor will be executed sequentially.

So the obvious question is: what `Distributor` is passed to the `runNestedSuites` method of `MasterSuite`? Because that `Distributor` is what's ultimately going to be passed to the `runNestedSuites` method of the `Suites` object that contains `D`, `E` and `F`.

Through experimentation with a debugger, I found that the `Distributor` is normally `None`. But if you mix the `ParallelTestExecution` trait into your `MasterSuite` class, you will get a `Some` instead, and I've verified that in a debugger too.

```scala
class MasterSuite extends Stepwise(
  new A,
  new B,
  new C,
  new Suites(new D, new E, new F)) with ParallelTestExecution
```

Now, the `MasterSuite` will run `A`, `B` and `C` sequentially and then start running the other suites in parallel.

So, problem solved? Unfortunately no, because while it apparently *started* running `D`, `E` and `F` in parallel, it didn't wait for them to *finish* and just declared them all successful – even though I deliberately added a failing test in `F` to see if everything works correctly. So as far as I can see, this is how it's supposed to be done and it's just broken.

Which leads me to my personal conclusion after many years of experience with ScalaTest: it's a bug-ridden piece of garbage, and I would highly recommend staying away from it. I'm sorry I can't give a more optimistic answer than that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer even if it's doesn't really fit my expectation

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/2181), which I just reported.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).